# Correct longtable \multicolumn exceeding page boundaries/margins

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I have problem with some of the `longtable` tables, as illustrated here:

[image]

Is there an easy way to make table wrap cell contents multi-line so that it does not exceed page margins?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) the duplicates this problem. That way community members can identify the problems much easier and hit the ground running. Specific to this example, you mention `\multicolumn` although it seems like you only have two columns in your `longtable`. Is there any addition (invisible) columns to your `longtable`?

Comment: TeX file was auto-generated by Sphinx. Here is sample that produced above table: http://pastebin.com/88qjEfdG

Comment: Using the `p{<width}` column type should fix it.  The `l` column type does not allow for line wrapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`longtable` column specifiers are exactly the same as standard latex `tabular` ones (or the extended set from the `array` package. so change `l` to `p{3cm}` and it will wrap the lines in that column to the specified width.

Comment: It would be really nifty if one could use a `X` column type.

Comment: @Werner The ltxtable package combines longtable and tabularx functionalities, and lets you do just that. :)